# Jquery fade image swap

Tags: jquery, image, fade

I've made this code. It changes the background image when I mouseover a box. 
However, I want the picture that comes in, to fade in. How do I do that? :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#box1").mouseover(function(){
        $("#background").addClass("hover1");
        $("#content").html(box1);
    });

    $("#box1").mouseout(function(){
        $("#background").removeClass("hover1");
        $("#content").html(content);            
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [switchClass](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/switchClass) or [toggleClass](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/toggleClass) like

```
$("p").click(function () {
    $(this).switchClass("ClassToBeRemoved", "ClassToBeAdded", 1000);
});

$('#foo').toggleClass(className, addOrRemove);
```

I think switchClass auita you

Comment: sure and this will be good if you share ur experience as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the jquery-ui switchClass might help you out:

[switchClass](http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I find it highly unfair to be voted down for something like this. Let's face it, there's nothing more to do than use the switchClass instruction with the right parameters, which is easily done by reading the link. There's nothing to explain, the answer is on topic, and even if i'm not saying it should be considered the right answer, getting downvoted is just not acceptable for me.

Comment: Well I'm sorry you feel that way.  Link only answers are terrible IMO.  We want to bring great content **to the site** - not to direct users away from here.  If you have a solution paste it here and give the link for reference.  No effort was put into this answer.